# How can I make functions common between assets/js and static/js?

Tags: hugo

I’m working on AMP project. I have an authorization callback that is defined in static/js (for some unknown reason, the callback should be defined in static/js). How I can make the function defined in assets/js to be visible in static/js?

My main js is included in HTML before that static/js and use this construction

```
{{ $js := resources.Get "js/custom.js" | js.Build }}
<script src="{{ $js.Permalink }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon mate, there is no reason to have it in static/js if you need it in assets/js.
But if that is some requirement beyond your control - symlink/mount it.
https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/5374

Honestly though, without a site repo, access to your codebase, etc. etc. Or a clear question, it's hard to give you more than that.

But, the actual answer to your question is:
https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/5374

Answer (score 0):

If you define some functions in custom.js with a global scope, they should be visible in the static JS files.

```
MyObject = {
    function1: function(...) {...},
    function2: function(...) {...}
    // other functions...
}
```

And then, they can be called from the other file with:

```
MyObject.function1();
```

Now, it might be possible that the file is not ready to be called, or that from your custom JS file you need to have the other static JS file loaded first. In that case, you can "wait" until everything is fully loaded.

```
MyObject = {
    function1: function(...) {...},
    function2: function(...) {...}
    // other functions...
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // Page is fully loaded. 
  MyObject.function1();
});
```

If this doesn't work, we'd need to understand a bit better the code that's inside static to see how you could achieve this.